# To make iOS app smaller than 50MB on cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, app-store

I'm using cocos2d for my game app and I want my app to be smaller than 50MB.
But I have too many image resources to avoid it.
I'm using CCSpriteFrameCache for my resources.
Is there any way download resources after downloading the app from the app store.
And is it allowed in Cocos2d?

best regards

Comment: reduce bundle size, for example by using pvr.ccz textures: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/

Answer (score 1):

Downloading images and other resources (but not code) is allowed, so you can store the image packs on a server. However, greeting the player with a downloading screen is not great. And make sure your bandwidth would be enough. You can use standard `NSURLConnection` in your code to download your data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download additional assets during app start up.

Just make sure your app has all of the assets it needs for the splash/intro scenes and first level and then download the rest while they are playing the first level. You will just have to fail gracefully if they don't have access to connectivity.

Check out this post for [Downloading Large Files in Asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002979/downloading-a-large-file-iphone-sdk).