# Error ("'()' is not identical to 'UInt8'") writing NSData bytes to NSOutputStream using the write function in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to build an asynchronous file download in Swift based on the [Erica Sadun's method](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/07-Asynchronous%20Downloads/). But I need it to handle bigger files, so I found [this answer about using a NSOutputStream instead of NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4003076/3877639), makes sense.

However, I can't get it to work. I get this error when I try adding the NSData bytes (in my NSURLConnection didReceiveData function) to the NSOutputStream write function: `'()' is not identical to 'UInt8'` on this row: `bytesWritten = self.downloadStream.write(data.bytes, maxLength: bytesLeftToWrite)`.

`data.bytes` is of the type `ConstUnsafePointer<()>` and the `.write()` function expects the type to be `ConstUnsafePointer<UInt8>`, so in that sense, the error make perfect sense. But since I'm new to iOS and of course Swift programming, I can't get my head around how to fix this.

**So, how do I convert the `data.bytes: ConstUnsafePointer<()>` to `ConstUnsafePointer<UInt8>` alt. make this work some other way?**

**My `didReceiveData` function:**

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {

    var bytesLeftToWrite: NSInteger = data.length
    var bytesWritten: NSInteger = 0

    while bytesLeftToWrite > 0 {

        bytesWritten = self.downloadStream.write(data.bytes, maxLength: bytesLeftToWrite)

        if bytesWritten == -1 {

            break

        }

        bytesLeftToWrite -= bytesWritten

        let responseExpectedlenght: NSNumber = NSNumber(longLong: self.downloadResponse!.expectedContentLength)
        let dataLength: NSNumber = NSNumber(long: data.length)

        self.downloadProgressPercentage = ((dataLength / responseExpectedlenght) * 100)

        println("Downloaded: \(self.downloadProgressPercentage)%")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast the pointer with `UnsafePointer()`:

```
bytesWritten = self.downloadStream.write(UnsafePointer(data.bytes), maxLength: bytesLeftToWrite)
```

There is also a problem in your write loop, because you always write the
*initial* bytes of the data object to the output stream.

It should probably look similar to this (untested):

```
var bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
var bytesLeftToWrite: NSInteger = data.length

while bytesLeftToWrite > 0 {
    let bytesWritten = self.downloadStream.write(bytes, maxLength: bytesLeftToWrite)
    if bytesWritten == -1 {
        break // Some error occurred ...
    }

    bytesLeftToWrite -= bytesWritten
    bytes += bytesWritten // advance pointer

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Easy as that, brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Niklas: You are welcome. But note that your write loop is not correct, because you write always the *initial* bytes of `data` to the output stream, not the *yet unwritten* bytes.

Comment: I hadn't though about that, since I ran in to trouble before I got that far. But I saw what you where saying I was just thinking about how to move the pointer when I saw your edit just now. Great, I'll have a go at something like that then! Thanks again!

Comment: (I'm not the down-voter; in fact I up-voted.) But, alas, in the shifting sands of Swift betas, I think this syntax has changed in beta 5. I use `var bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buffer)`.

Comment: @Rob: You are completely right, and that is much more elegant. - There are probably a lot of answers that need to be revised for beta 5. I will have a look at mine later. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 2):

I'd would suggest availing yourself of `enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock`, because `NSData` no longer guarantees that the underlying data will be held in a single contiguous memory block. For example, according to the documentation for `didReceiveData` of the `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` protocol:

> Because the `NSData` object is often pieced together from a number of different data objects, whenever possible, use `NSData`’s `enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:` method to iterate through the data rather than using the `bytes` method (which flattens the `NSData` object into a single memory block).

Thus, for example, you could do an extension of `NSOutputStream` that writes the contents of a `NSData`:

```
extension NSOutputStream {

    /// Write contents of NSData to `NSOutputStream`
    ///
    /// - parameter data:   The `NSData` being written to the stream.
    ///
    /// - returns:          The number of bytes written. In case of error, returns -1.

    func writeData(data: NSData) -> Int {
        var totalBytesWritten = 0

        data.enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock() {
            buffer, range, stop in

            var bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buffer)
            var bytesWritten = 0
            var bytesLeftToWrite = range.length

            while bytesLeftToWrite > 0 {
                bytesWritten = self.write(bytes, maxLength: bytesLeftToWrite)
                if bytesWritten < 0 {
                    stop.initialize(true)
                    totalBytesWritten = -1
                    return
                }

                bytes += bytesWritten
                bytesLeftToWrite -= bytesWritten
                totalBytesWritten += bytesWritten
            }
        }

        return totalBytesWritten
    }

}
```

Note, the technique of stopping the enumeration in case of error, namely `stop.initialize(true)`, requires Xcode 6 beta 4 or later. Earlier versions of Xcode (and associated compiler) used a more awkward construction for updating the boolean reference to stop the enumeration.

Comment: BTW, I'm not suggesting you change the accepted answer, because Martin got to the root of your error message (+1 Martin). I'm just suggesting that you don't use the `data.bytes` construction, but rather enumerate through the `NSData`.