# unsigned char in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In Obj-C this code is used to convert an NSData to unsigned char:

```
unsigned char *dataToSentToPrinter = (unsigned char *)malloc(commandSize);
```

In Swift unsigned char is supposedly called CUnsignedChar, but how do i convert an NSData object to CUnsignedChar in Swift?

Comment: Your Objective-C code *allocates* an unsigned char buffer, I cannot see how it *converts* NSData. Perhaps you can explain better what you actually need to achieve.

Comment: It takes the data from the commandSize which is NSData, convert might be the wrong word, but I simply need that data to become an unsigned char buffer.

Comment: I'm trying to convert an Obj-C function from the StarIO SDK which looks like this http://pastebin.com/dBCz2bv0, if that gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for:

```
let commandsToPrint: NSData = ...

// Create char array with the required size:
var dataToSentToPrinter = [CUnsignedChar](count: commandsToPrint.length, repeatedValue: 0)

// Fill with bytes from NSData object:
commandsToPrint.getBytes(&dataToSentToPrinter, length: sizeofValue(dataToSentToPrinter))
```

*Update:* Actually you don't need to copy the data at all (neither in the
Objective-C code nor in Swift). It is sufficient to have a *pointer* to the data.
So your code could look like this (compare 
[Error ("'()' is not identical to 'UInt8'") writing NSData bytes to NSOutputStream using the write function in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080661/error-is-not-identical-to-uint8-writing-nsdata-bytes-to-nsoutputstrea) 
for a similar problem):

```
let dataToSentToPrinter = UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>(commandsToPrint.bytes)
let commandSize = commandsToPrint.length
var totalAmountWritten = 0

while totalAmountWritten < commandSize {
    let remaining = commandSize - totalAmountWritten
    let amountWritten = starPort.writePort(dataToSentToPrinter, totalAmountWritten, remaining)
    totalAmountWritten += amountWritten
    // ...
}
```