# Declare unsigned char array in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

What I used to do in obj-c:

```
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

what I tried in swift found here [unsigned char in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299895/unsigned-char-in-swift):

```
let cHMAC = [CUnsignedChar](count: CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
```

However this does not build because *extra argument count in call*

Any ideas how I can translate the first code to swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the `Array` constructor

```
init(count: Int, repeatedValue: T)
```

and there two errors: You forgot the `repeatedValue:` argument, and `CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH`, which is mapped to Swift as an `Int32`, needs to be cast to `Int`:

```
let cHMAC = [CUnsignedChar](count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25762128/1187415 for a full example.

Comment: maybe you can help me out on another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655999/create-hash-in-swift-using-key-and-message