# Create hash in swift using key and message

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to create an SHA1 hmac hash of a string using a key in swift. In obj-c I used this and it worked great:

```
+(NSString *)sha1FromMessage:(NSString *)message{

    const char *cKey  = [API_KEY cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [message cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%s", cData);

    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    NSData *HMACData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

    const unsigned char *buffer = (const unsigned char *)[HMACData bytes];
    NSMutableString *HMAC = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:HMACData.length * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < HMACData.length; ++i){
        [HMAC appendFormat:@"%02hhx", buffer[i]];
    }
    return HMAC;
}
```

However now I am having a hard time to translate this into swift. This is what I have so far:

```
static func sha1FromMessage(message: String){

        let cKey = RestUtils.apiKey.cStringUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
        let cData = message.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let cHMAC = [CUnsignedChar](count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)

        CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, cKey.count, cData, cData.count, cHMAC)
        ...
}
```

and this line

```
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, cKey.count, cData, cData.count, cHMAC)
```

already gives me an error *Int is not convertible to CCHmacAlgorithm*. Any ideas how to translate the obj-c code to swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of the `CCHmac()` function has the type `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` because
that's where the result is *written to*. You have to declare `cHMAC` as *variable*
and pass it as an *in-out expression* with `&`. In addition, some type conversions
are necessary:

```
var cHMAC = [CUnsignedChar](count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), cKey, UInt(cKey.count), cData, UInt(cData.count), &cHMAC)
```

Comment: +1 thank you! Can you help me translate the rest of the function?

Comment: @artworkadシ: It seems that only the hex string generation is missing, and that is shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25762128/1187415, to which I pointed you already in an answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Apple enum values are defined differently in Swift. Instead of `kCCHmacAlgSHA1`, it's probably defined like `CCHmacAlgorithm.SHA1`.

This is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24411522/2708650