# error while converting NSData objectiveC code to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsstring, nsdata

I tried converting this code in Objective C to Swift,

```
- (IBAction) sendMessage {

    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"msg:%@", inputMessageField.text];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    inputMessageField.text = @"";

}
```

below is my swift code.

```
@IBAction func sendMessage() {

        var response  = NSString.localizedStringWithFormat("msg:\(inputMessageField?.text)")
        var data = NSData(Data :response , dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        outputStream(write:data.bytes, maxLength:data.length);
        inputMessageField?.text = ""

    }
```

I get an error telling that a data is an extra argument. Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `NSData(Data :response , dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding)` method. You are probably looking for

```
let data = 
response.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

your whole code should look like this:

```
let response  = NSString.localizedStringWithFormat("msg:\(inputMessageField?.text)")
if let data = response.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    outputStream(write:data.bytes, maxLength:data.length);
    inputMessageField?.text = ""
}
else {
    println("could not convert response \"\(response)\" to NSData")
}
```

use let when ever possible, and check if the failable initalizers return a value

Comment: Thanku:)(write:UnsafePointer<void>, maxLength:Int)-> $T6   is not identical to NSOutputstream.  I get this error for the code above.

Comment: @Jeyanthu: This should work: `outputStream.write(UnsafePointer(data.bytes), maxLength:data.length)`. Also note that writing to a stream might actually write *less* bytes than you provided. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/25080834/1187415.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for `NSData(Data :response , dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding)` does not exist.

you can convert like this

```
var data = NSData(data :response.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!)
```

**UPDATED**

The method `outputStream.write()` expects `UInt8[]` array, so you've to convert your data to `UInt8[] Array`.

Your code should be,

```
@IBAction func sendMessage() {
    var response  = NSString.localizedStringWithFormat("msg:\(inputMessageField?.text)")
    var data = NSData(Data :response , dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding)        
    outputStream.write(UnsafePointer(data.bytes), maxLength:data.length)
    inputMessageField?.text = ""
}
```

Comment: (write:UnsafePointer<void>, maxLength:Int)-> $T6 is not identical to NSOutputstream. I get this error for the code above

Comment: it's because `outputstream` expects `UInt8[] array`, please see the updated code

Comment: and also the method you're using `outputStream(write())` expects `3 parameters` where it's expecting `UnsafePointer<void>`, but you don't need that method to write into stream,

Comment: Your `buffer` contains only zeros, not the bytes from `data`.